# Byte-Buddy reference generated method

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm adding a method to an existing class during compilation using byte-buddy.

The issue comes when I try to reference that generated method on the Java code I get a `cannot find symbol` error and my guess is that the method will only be generated at the end of the compilation so the Java compiler was no way to know that this method exists.

Is possible to do some workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Byte Buddy operates on byte code, after compilation completes. The only way to do this would be if one class was in a different module that was already post-processed. Otherwise, this is not possible.